# Eclipse junit runner that isolates output for individual tests which may be viewed in console individually?

Tags: eclipse, junit

Imagine a test suite with a dozen tests. Each might print somet stuff to System.out via a logger etc. The wish or problem is that it is not possible to have the console only show the output for the selected test. The console shows everything. Is tehre a plugin or way to achieve my wish ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have Eclipse run only one test in a suite, by choosing the test on the Run Configurations dialog (the "Test method" field).

By the way, this isn't really a programming question.  You might get more response by posting the question to superuser.com.